# gdal cannot work when using openMP in c++ for reading a dataset?

Tags: gdal, rasterio, multithreading

```
 void generate( GDALDataset  *ds)
{
    int tcount = (1 + abs(tmaxx - tminx))*(1 + abs(tmaxy - tminy));
    GDALDriver* jpegDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("PNG");
    int tz = tmaxz;
    for (int ty = tmaxy; ty >= tminy; ty--)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)   
        for (int tx = tminx; tx <= tmaxx; tx++){

            // TODO tilefilename is exits
            int googleY = (pow(2, tz) - 1) - ty;
            string tileDir = "D:\\test2\\" + to_string(tz) + "\\" + to_string(tx);
            string tilefilename = tileDir + "\\" +to_string(googleY) + "." + tileext;
            create_dir(tileDir.c_str());
            Envelope b = mercator->TileBounds(tx, ty, tz);
            int * rwxy;
            rwxy = geo_query(b,querysize);
            int rx, ry, rxsize, rysize, wx, wy, wxsize, wysize;
            rx = *(rwxy+0);
            ry = *(rwxy + 1);
            rxsize = *(rwxy + 2);
            rysize = *(rwxy + 3);
            wx = *(rwxy + 4);
            wy = *(rwxy + 5);
            wxsize = *(rwxy + 6);
            wysize = *(rwxy + 7);

            GDALDataset *dstile;
            char **papszOptions = NULL;
            dstile = mem_drv->Create("temp", tilesize, tilesize, 3, GDT_Byte, papszOptions);

            int bandNum;
            bandNum = ds->GetRasterCount();    //波段数
            bandNum = 3;
            int depth = GDALGetDataTypeSize(ds->GetRasterBand(1)->GetRasterDataType());//8;    //图像深度
            size_t imgBufNum = (size_t)wxsize * wysize * bandNum*depth;
            GByte *data = new GByte[imgBufNum];

            ds->RasterIO(GF_Read, rx, ry, rxsize, rysize, data, wxsize, wysize,
                GDT_Byte, bandNum, nullptr, bandNum*depth, wxsize*bandNum*depth, depth);
            if (tilesize == querysize)
            {
                //写入
                dstile->RasterIO(GF_Write, wx, wy, wxsize, wysize, data, wxsize, wysize,
                GDT_Byte, bandNum, nullptr, bandNum*depth, wxsize*bandNum*depth, depth);    
                dstile->GetRasterBand(4)->SetNoDataValue(0);
            }
            else
            {


                GDALDataset *dsquery;
                dsquery = mem_drv->Create("temp", querysize, querysize, 3, GDT_Byte, papszOptions);
                dsquery->RasterIO(GF_Write, wx, wy, wxsize, wysize, data, wxsize, wysize,
                    GDT_Byte, bandNum, nullptr, bandNum*depth, wxsize*bandNum*depth, depth);
                scale_query_to_tile(dsquery, dstile);
                GDALClose((GDALDatasetH)dsquery);


            }

            delete[] data;
            data = NULL;
            clock_t start, finish;
            start = clock();
            GDALDataset *poDstDS;
            poDstDS = jpegDriver->CreateCopy(tilefilename.c_str(), dstile, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            //Once we're done, close properly the dataset */
            if (poDstDS != NULL)
                GDALClose((GDALDatasetH)poDstDS);
            GDALClose((GDALDatasetH)dstile);
        }
    }
    //GetLocalTime(&st);
    }
```

The above is the main code, and the error happen in"**ds->RasterIO(GF_Read, ...)"**. and the error is " The error is “An access violation occurs when the location 0x000001D93A661000 is written”. "  How can I fixed it or any other better solution?

Comment: What error? Do you get an error message? You aren't going outside the bounds of your raster are you? What does TileBounds give you.. Projected coordinates? Offsets and sizes for RasterIO are in **pixels from the origin (upper left usually)** not world units. imgBufNum needs to be divided by 8 - you are using far too much memory, depth of 8 bits = 1 byte.

Comment: @MichaelStimson  The error is “An access violation occurs when the location 0x000001D93A661000 is written”. If I remove the  "#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)"  and don't use the openMP, the other codes is ok. The RasterIO  function can not be used in openMP ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure about open MP. GDAL objects are thread safe but I think you need thread state STA https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112(v=vs.85).aspx and not MTA. It sounds like you've got a MTA thread and it can't access the data properly because the dataset is a STA object...you should edit that error message into your question, it's kind of important information.

Comment: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQMiscellaneous It mensions some about the thread safety.  The same GDALDataset should not be accessed by several threads.

Comment: What's not seen here is how the GDALDataset  \*ds is opened, is it opened with open or openshared? http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#a46a02c21047d78f88f8abb1ff6b14ae2  this should return a different dataset for each thread. *Starting with GDAL 1.6.0, if GDALOpenShared() is called on the same pszFilename from two different threads, a different GDALDataset object will be returned as it is not safe to use the same dataset from different threads, unless the user does explicitly use mutexes in its code*